# How can I offset boxes to match steps?

Tags: gnuplot

My application deploys to CentOS 6 and CentOS 7. I have just found out that Gnuplot 4.4 (which is the latest I can use on CentOS 6, for logistical reasons) does not support `fillsteps`, so my lovely graphs are not rendering there.

Said graphs have a series of `steps` for a bounding line, and a series of `fillsteps` to create a solid colour. (I'm also faking a stacked plot, but never mind that.)

I reckon I can use `steps` and `boxes` instead, but `boxes` are offset on the axis by half a tic. Can I shuffle them over in an efficient and expressive way? Or perhaps I should be coming at this completely differently?

---

#### Original code

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font ",10" size 576, 231
set border back
set grid
set xzeroaxis lt -1
set style line 1 lc rgbcolor "#4E9EF3"
set style line 2 lc rgbcolor "#B23F3F"
set timefmt "%s"
set xdata time
set xlabel "Time (+00:00)"
set format x "%H:%M"
set offset graph 0, graph 0, graph 0.05, graph 0.05
set xrange [571795200:571881600]
set yrange [0:]
plot 'data.csv' using 1:($2+$3) with fillsteps ls 1 fs solid 0.3 noborder notitle,
    '' using 1:($2+$3) with steps ls 1 notitle,
    '' using 1:2 with fillsteps ls 2 fs solid 0.3 noborder notitle,
    '' using 1:2 with steps ls 2 notitle
```

---

#### Attempt at replacing fillsteps with boxes

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font ",10" size 576, 231
set border back
set grid
set xzeroaxis lt -1
set style line 1 lc rgbcolor "#4E9EF3"
set style line 2 lc rgbcolor "#B23F3F"
set boxwidth 1.0 relative
set timefmt "%s"
set xdata time
set xlabel "Time (+00:00)"
set format x "%H:%M"
set offset graph 0, graph 0, graph 0.05, graph 0.05
set xrange [571795200:571881600]
set yrange [0:]
plot 'data.csv' using 1:($2+$3) with boxes ls 1 fs solid 0.3 noborder notitle,
    '' using 1:($2+$3) with steps ls 1 notitle,
    '' using 1:2 with boxes ls 2 fs solid 0.3 noborder notitle,
    '' using 1:2 with steps ls 2 notitle
```

[image: Sample of graph as it plots now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My input data happens to be evenly spaced, with the X axis increment known to the calling code.

So, instead of:

```
plot 'data.csv' using 1:2 with fillsteps ls 2 fs solid 0.3 noborder notitle
```

I can do:

```
# (for example)
barwidth = 900

set boxwidth 1.0 relative

plot 'data.csv' using ($1+barwidth/2.0):2 with boxes ls 2 fs solid 0.3 noborder notitle
```

… and this appears to provide consistent results.